# Quand écrire ce « -t- » sorti des méandres de la phonétique?

Tags: orthographe, phonétique, liaisons, trait-d-union, euphonie

Dois-je écrire « Y répond-on ? » comme ceci, ou « Y répond**-t-**on ? » comme cela ?

Dans le cas général, ça m'a l'air de dépendre de la phonétique des deux mots liés.
Y a-t-il des règles ou est-ce au petit bonheur la chance ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ce *t* s'appelle **t euphonique**, son usage est plutôt bien décrit [icitte](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2513) par l'[OQLF](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/).

> On appelle *t euphonique* ou *t analogique* le *t* ajouté entre le verbe et un pronom sujet de troisième personne (*il, elle* et *on*) lorsqu'il y a inversion de ce verbe et de ce sujet. Cette inversion se produit dans une structure interrogative ou dans une phrase incise. L'ajout du *t* euphonique n'est exigé que lorsque le verbe se termine par un *-e* muet ou par un *-a*, et avec les verbes *vaincre* et *convaincre*.

Et un peu plus loin la réponse à ta question sur *répondre* :

> Le *t* euphonique n'étant nécessaire que lorsque le verbe finit par une voyelle, sa présence est superflue avec les verbes se terminant par un *-d* qui se prononce *-t*; on écrira donc : *répond-il ? entend-elle ? prend-on ?* et non *répond-t-il ? entend-t-elle ? prend-t-on ?*