# « Il pourra être » ou « Il pourra-t-être » ?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, conjugaison, liaisons, euphonie

> **Cette question est un doublon de :**
>   [Quand écrire ce « -t- » sorti des méandres de la phonétique?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/956/quand-ecrire-ce-t-sorti-des-meandres-de-la-phonetique)

Quelle est la forme la plus adaptée et pourquoi, par rapport à quelles règles ?

Je sais qu'au futur simple interrogatif, on rajoute ce `t` de de cette manière « Pourra-t-il ? », mais je ne trouve pas la règle correspondante qui pourrait m'aider à répondre à ma question…

Merci d'avance pour votre aide !

Comment: "Pourra être" ne se dit pas, on dira plutôt : 
"Il sera" ou si c'est du conditionnel "il pourrait être". Du coup, plus besoin du "t".

Comment: Quelle règle interdit l'usage de "Pourra être" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On appelle ce `t` le [T euphonique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_euphonique).

On ne l'ajoute qu'entre un verbe et un pronom (sujet) qui lui est associé.
Plus d'informations dans [Quand écrire ce « -t- » sorti des méandres de la phonétique ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/957/79).

Comment: Parfait, merci beaucoup : cette histoire de [t euphonique](http://66.46.185.79/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=t+euphonique) répond parfaitement à ma question !

Comment: L'explication seule c'est bien mais alors quant à la question d'origine "Quelle est la forme la plus adaptée"?