# What does "cela" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: grammaire, traduction

Example sentence:

> Combien de temps **cela** prend-t-il pour faire la correspondance ?

Translated into English, this says ***how long does it take to make a connection?*** What I don't undertand in this sentence, however, is how the word ***cela*** fits in with the rest of it all. What exactly is its function in there?

Comment: It s "prend-il" and not "prend-t-il"

Comment: Thank you. That was a typo. I was typing that out by hand and missed the "t" for some reason.

Comment: There is no t, that's the point.

Comment: The phrase book I took it from does have a "t" there.

Comment: Concerning the euphonic/analogic T in French: [Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=t+euphonique&T3.x=12&T3.y=11&id=2513), [Université d'Ottawa](http://www.visezjuste.uottawa.ca/pages/orthographe/t_euphonique.html), [Le Figaro](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/frtraitunionquestion.php), [Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/perd-t-il-vend-t-il), etc. Sources are numerous and all point to the same conclusion. I believe you can trust users here more than your book...

Comment: And of course, it's also been discussed right here on [French Stack Exchange](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/956/quand-%C3%A9crire-ce-t-sorti-des-m%C3%A9andres-de-la-phon%C3%A9tique), with more of the same rules leading to the same spelling and correct usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without *cela*, the sentence is:

> Combien de temps prend-il pour faire la correspondance ?

In this case, we basically assume "il" to be someone, as in
"How long does **he** take to make a connection?".

So we add a *cela*:

> Combien de temps cela prend-il pour faire la correspondance ?
>   Which means, "How long does **it** take to make a connection?"

Actually, the interrogative form of "X fait" (replace "X" by any subject except "il, elle, on" and "fait" by any verb) is not "fait-X...?" 
but "X fait-il...?". See

> Combien de temps cela fait-il que nous ne nous sommes pas vus?
>
> Cela fait 3 ans.

And

> Combien de temps cela va-t-il durer ?
>
> Cela va durer une heure.

But also

> Quel problème Marc a-t-il rencontré ?
>
> Comment Marie fait-elle pour supporter ça ?
>
> Combien de fois ton chien est-il sorti de sa niche ?

Comment: Could you provide English translations for your examples?

Comment: Just write them in parentheses after the corresponding French examples.